# How can I bind command to Entry box when it is in focus?

Tags: python, tkinter

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580770-combobox-autocomplete/

Working with the class above. As of right now, a drop down list only appears when you start typing in into the entry box, auto completing the word you're typing in.

How can i create a method that makes the full list appear when the entry box is in focus?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `<FocusIn>` event to call a function when the widget gains focus.

```
def do_something(event):
    ...

entry = tk.Entry(...)
entry.bind('<FocusIn>', do_something)
```

Comment: Hi! My problem is that I don't fully understand the class given, so I'm not sure which function I could use to make the list appear

Comment: @StevenCunden: *"to make the list appear"*: Use `combobox_autocomplete._build_listbox(combobox_autocomplete.list_of_items)`